# Variance-bias tradeoff problem and how Bayesian and non-Bayesian approaches perform in a big data setting

Tags: bayesian, bias, unbiased-estimator, large-data, bias-variance-tradeoff

When it comes to deal with the variance-bias tradeoff issue, I assume that bias is automatically induced in the Bayesian approach just from using a prior, while non-Bayesian approaches use math to determine whether a particular estimator is biased or not.

Now comes big data, which may solve the variance-bias tradeoff issue. My question is, is it possible to formulate a general principle on the performance of Bayesian and non-Bayesian approaches when dealing with the variance-bias tradeoff issue in a big data setting? I.e. one outperforms the other (solves the issue faster) for the same model complexity?

Comment: We don't assume unbiasedness of an estimator based on the data, we use math to determine whether a particular estimator is biased or not.   As the amount of data gets large, some estimators are consistent - again, determined by mathematical analysis, not by assumption - and others are not.  Asymptotically, Bayesian and efficient frequentist approaches converge under a fairly broad set of conditions, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%E2%80%93von_Mises_theorem).   Note also that your last statement would appear to be about algorithm implementation, not about statistics per se.

Comment: @jbowman I think when you state that "we use math to determine whether a particular estimator is biased or not" you are implicitly stating that data is unbiased, the methods you can use to manipulate it might be biased, which agrees to my point. Regarding my last statement, yes, the question is framed in a Machine Learning application, but I don't think this is inconsistent with my question about which approach is more favoured in mitigating the variance-bias tradeoff in a big data setting.

Comment: I think you may be confused about what "bias" is... it's a property of an estimator.   If the data isn't representative of the underlying data generating process, that's a different problem.

Comment: @jbowman I agree. Although off topic I changed the text. The question still remains. From your comment it seems that no clear answer can be given.